# How to get the signed document back as an attachment

Tags: docusignapi, servicenow

I am actually testing Docusign integration in servicenow.
For now I am actually testing API Google ARC.
I manage to send the enveloppe to docuement to be signed.
Then when the recipient signed the document, an email validation is received in servicenow to the address "@service-now.com" but in order to get the signed document I need to fetch it from docusign portal and download it

URL:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{account id}/envelopes/
```

Here is the POST body that I am sending to Docusign:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Sent from the DocuSign REST API",
    "documents": [{
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "mydoc.pdf",
        "documentBase64": "......."   }],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "xxxxxx@hotmail.com",
            "name": "xxxxx yyyyy",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "routingOrder": "1"
        }],
  "carbonCopies": [{
                "email": "<instance>@service-now.com",
                "name": "SN",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            }]
    }
}
```

The reason why I try to get the signed document as an attachment is that in Service-now when the Inbound email is receive, I can directly run an action script which will be then retrieve the attached file automatically and associated to the current record.

Any idea how to get the attachment to the signed email validation?

Please note that I have a demo free account in Docusign

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution by going to my Admin profile in Docusign and set the attachment option to be handle